# pruning string values from a multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have multi indexed survey data in pandas dataframe. One subset of it is given below. I am trying to drop NA(well they are not exactly NAs, they are infact one liners) from the rows and than have to sort the values in ascending order and take count of each rank for every item.

rank these items on a scale of 1-5

```
                               X   1 2 1 1 2 NA 3 4 5 1 2 4 3 NA

                               Y   2 2 3 1 3 1 NA NA 1 4 5 1 4

                               Z   1 4 5 3 1 2  2 1  2 3 5 1 NA
```

rank these items on a scale of 1-3

```
                               A  1 2 1 3 2 3 NA NA 1 1 3 2 2 NA

                               B  2 2 3 NA 1 1 NA 1  2 1 1 3 NA 1

                               C  1 3 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 NA 1 2 NA 1
```

Using the following code to proceed in my data transforming process. however have hit a road block while trying drop the string values and sort the integers.

`df = df.T
 df.set_index(df.columns[0], append=True, inplace=True)
 df = pd.to_numeric(df, errors='coerce')`

any advise regarding this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Use df.dropna() to drop NAs. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Comment: i tried it but df.dropna() drops the complete row or column where ever there is NAN value. I just want to remove those fields where there is NAN and keep rest for further processing

Comment: It will basically be impossible to drop them completely -- in a DataFrame, you can't have in a some rows with 3 columns of values and others with only two (NA values, as a matter of fact, already represent cells with no value, like null values in SQL). If your ultimate goal is to convert your data to integers, you could use something like `df.fillna(0).applymap(int)`, since `0` values will have no meaning to your data anyway.

Comment: hmm.. thats a solution, but when i am executing the following code it is droping the first two indexes as well which contain the tag and the element name.                                                        
                        `for name, values in df.iteritems():
                                df[name] = pd.to_numeric(df[name], errors='coerce')
                         df.fillna(0).applymap(int)`